# как добавить новый элемент в JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eсть такой код. Я хочу добавить текст в JSON, который был введен в input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="numsarea" class="display">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: вот [здесь](https://codepen.io/shimizurei/pen/RNQXvP?editors=0010)техника исполнения